# How to use .png icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons, png

I'm pretty sure I you can't do that directly, but maybe there is a workaround which I am not aware of?

But, if nothing else, someone points to the good png-to-ico batch converter, well, so be it, I'll accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Free png to ico convertor](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1774-rel-aveiconifier-2/)

[Direct download link for AveIconifier2](http://www.box.net/shared/v3hse8lki5)

Comment: Thanks, this is nice program, but I don't see batch support and ico's seem to be limited to 128*128 maximum.