# How to change icons set for all common filetype in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, desktop-icons

I'm using windows 8.1 and want to replace all my current icon set with [Free File Icons](https://github.com/teambox/Free-file-icons). How to do that?

These are the list of free icons offered in the set:

[image]

> AAC, AI, AIFF, AVI, C, CPP, CSS, DAT, DMG, DOC, EXE, FLV, GIF, H, HPP, HTML, ICS, JAVA, JPG, KEY, MID, MP3, MP4, MPG, PDF, PHP, PNG,
>   PPT, PSD, PY, QT, RAR, RB, RTF, SQL, TIFF, TXT, WAV, XLS, XML, YML,
>   ZIP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article
[How to Change the Default Icon of a File Extension in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/57455-file-extension-icon-change-default-icon.html)
lists two methods.

**Method 1** : Use the program [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).

[image: image 1]

**Method 2** : Directly change the information in the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext`

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Adding to this: you can create a single REG file if you want to replace them all at once. PS: ALWAYS backup registry before messing with it.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with a program called "Default Programs editor" downloadable from here: http://defaultprogramseditor.com/

Clicking Icon will enable you to change the default icon for all filetypes. This is compatible with windows 8.1

Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: does this work with .png icons ?  --  Same question for HarryMC

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe you would have to first convert the .png files into .ico files.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert those png's into ico's so windows can recognize them as icons.

[How to use .png icons in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/289153/how-to-use-png-icons-in-windows-7)

Google offers plenty of freeware apps or here is an online method that might help.

http://www.convertico.com/

Then you can point the registry at the icons as mentioned by HarryMC.